# modify code to start copy from under a cell named "Sales organization"

Tags: excel, vba

Below code is for retrieving header data from first sheet (starting in cell A1) then copying range from second row.
I would like to modify this to retrieve header date from first sheet: it is the row starting with Cell containing value "Sales organization", then copy the range from all sheet starting from under the header (Cell containing value "Sales organization") into sheet Master.

Can someone please help me to modify it so?
Many thanks!

```
Sub CopyFromWorksheets()
    Dim wrk As Workbook
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim trg As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim colCount As Integer

    Set wrk = ActiveWorkbook

    For Each sht In wrk.Worksheets
        If sht.Name = "Master" Then
            MsgBox "There is a worksheet called as 'Master'." & vbCrLf & _
            "Please remove or rename this worksheet since 'Master' would be" & _
            "the name of the result worksheet of this process.", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Error"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next sht

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set trg = wrk.Worksheets.Add(After:=wrk.Worksheets(wrk.Worksheets.Count))
    trg.Name = "Master"
    Set sht = wrk.Worksheets(1)
    colCount = sht.Cells(1, 255).End(xlToLeft).Column
    With trg.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, colCount)
        .Value = sht.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, colCount).Value
        .Font.Bold = True
    End With

    For Each sht In wrk.Worksheets
        If sht.Index = wrk.Worksheets.Count Then
            Exit For
        End If
        Set rng = sht.Range(sht.Cells(2, 1), sht.Cells(65536, 1).End(xlUp).Resize(, colCount))
        trg.Cells(65536, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Value = rng.Value
    Next sht
    trg.Columns.AutoFit


    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `WorksheetFunction.MATCH` to find the column of interest - after that, copying the column should be easy:

```
theColumn = WorksheetFunction.MATCH("Sales organization", Range("1:1"), 0)
```

which will find the first column in the first row that has exactly `Sales organization` in it.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835873.aspx

**update** if there is a chance that there is no cell with `"Sales organization"` in it, you might want to trap this - since it would generate an error (as pointed out by D_Bester). Something like this:

```
theColumn = -1       ' set an "impossible" value 
                     ' - it will get overwritten by a successful call to MATCH
On Error Resume Next ' ignore error in the next line and keep going
theColumn = WorksheetFunction.MATCH("Sales organization", Range("1:1"), 0)
On Error GoTo 0 ' turn error handling off again
if theColumn > 0 Then
   ' do whatever you were planning - you found a match
Else
   ' do something else, since  you didn't find a match...
End If
```

Comment: This will return `Run-time error 1004: Unable to get the Match property of the WorksheetFunction class` when a match is not found. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895517/method-range-of-object-global-failed-in-excel-macro/21895895#21895895

Comment: @D_Bester - thanks for pointing that out; I have fixed (a slightly different approach than the one you used in your linked answer, but I think valid all the same; and it prevents you having to call `MATCH` twice....)